# SQL Server Linked Server fallback

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a web app which connects to a SQL Server 2012 Express which uses the resources I'm about to describe.

I've configured a single linked server atm pointing to an odbc DSN - MSDASQL provider (and quite a few views and stored procedures collecting from that lksv).

What I would like to do is to add another linked server using the same type of connection, and every time a query is made against that server, intercept that query with a sp_testlinkedserver and if that fails switch to the other linked server (by changing a synonym to point to the linked server or something ).

Is this doable from SQL Server? I know I could program it some way through the web app (php), but I'd like this thing to be completely transparent. Also I would rather not modify every view and sp if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to provide a automatic failover on the sql server side, this plan should do the trick.

You run a SQL Agent permanently or a check procedure in front of your real query. It should try to access the linked server. If it's not available you can drop and recreate a linked server which points to the available endpoint. This way you just need to point to this single linked server which is always available - except both endpoints where offline.

Comment: I went for the sp path (wrapped the queries in stored procedures) and used sp_testlinkedserver on the entries of a very small table with 2 columns, lksrvname and an active flag and switch between them on timeouts (also set connection timeout to the minimum of 1 second, because the MSSQL machine and the 2 lksrvrs were in the same subnet with pings <1ms between them). As for the queries I created them dynamically (following a post on dynamic openqueries) concating the active linked server name. It's not very fast but it does exactly what i want.

Comment: Well if a short downtime is acceptable you can run it as an SQL Agent Job which will run every 5 minutes, minute, 30 secs. etc. If you detect a downtime, just run sp_setnetname to change the mirror partner. This will prevent your queries from slowing down.